# CKE editor not showing up until I upload an image?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

If I add content as admin, it works fine right from the beginning(using admin overlay).

[image: admin overlay]

But if I login as another role then CKE editor wont be neabled until I upload the image. [image: ckeEditor]

In Both roles FULL HTML is the default text format.
What might be the reason for this?

When I upload an image, then CKE editor shows up

[image: cke editor after upload]

Comment: Check your log for any errors. Also open firebug and see if you get any javascript errors. I had a similar problem with ckeditor which was solved by enabling "Aggregate JavaScript files". Also clear your caches (both drupal's and your browser's)

Comment: Indeed there is a Javascript error with WYSIWYG ![js error](http://i45.tinypic.com/9atwmr.png) but Aggregate Javascript files did not help in my occasion :(

Comment: Better google it. I see there are more with the same problem. http://drupal.org/node/1181562 Try to see if you can find a solution.

Comment: Indeed that was my problem. I try to insert a static jquery menu to my theme and to be able to do that I needed to insert jquery.min.js which has a conflict with WYSIWYG; probably that one is using jquery_update module. When I remove my custom javascripts and jquery.min.js the problem is solved but I have to find a way to make them work together